# SD Card Pin State During Hot Insertion

Tags: microcontroller, spi, sd

I'm working on a project in which I'm forced to connect an SD card to a shared SPI bus with some other peripherals. I need to make sure a hot insertion event won't corrupt any ongoing data transfer on the bus, but I can't find any information on the power-up state of the card drivers in the simplified specifications. Does anyone know if the CLK, CMD, and DAT0 pins on an SD card are guaranteed to be high-impedance during a hot insertion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hot insertion on a shared SPI bus won't work at all with SD cards. One must remember that SD cards come up in SD mode, where the CS is *active high*.

You need to explicity switch the card to SPI mode before you can use other devices on the same SPI bus, this is obviously not possible when you insert a card during another SPI transaction.

Either use a bus driver chip to connect the SD card or use a different SPI bus, for example software SPI using GPIOs.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into using a bus switch to isolate the card until my software is ready to initialize it.